# WSOP 2011: -1% badge - what it is for?

Tags: tournament, wsop

Can you please explain what does this -1% badge some WSOP players wear do?
Thanks

[image: Badge]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a -, it's actually the word TEAM very small.  Players wearing the patch have pledged to donate 1% of their winnings to [Bad Beat on Cancer](http://preventcancer.org/badbeatoncancer/), an initiative of the Prevent Cancer Foundation.

Comment: Oh, so much for the low res recordings I watch. Thanks for the clarification.